# Which IDE supports CoffeeScript debugging (Source Mapping, Breakpoints & Call Stack) for Node.js apps?

Tags: node.js, debugging, ide, coffeescript, breakpoints

I'm still pretty new to the whole CoffeeScript scene.

Are there any IDEs out there that support debugging of CoffeeScript source code running on Node.js?

I'm hoping for something where I can set a breakpoint within a .coffee file and see a call stack and inspect variables.

WebStorm doesn't seem to fit the bill yet. [WEB-2389](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2389#tab=Comments.)

It appears that there is a solution for this client side using [CoffeeScriptRedux](https://github.com/michaelficarra/CoffeeScriptRedux) in Chrome. [Example](http://ryanflorence.com/2012/coffeescript-source-maps/)

Are there other options? [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/)?

**Update**
After checking in on this issue again nearly a year later I came across this [JetBrains help document](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debugging-coffeescript.html).  It looks like it supports debugging server side coffee script... finally!

Comment: Just started looking into CoffeeScript myself. How coffee be the most popular language on GitHub without any decent tools for editing and debugging beats me..

Answer (score 4):

JetBrains products support debugging CoffeeScript with a combination of the JetBrains Chrome Plugin and Coffee-script-redux.

http://www.jetbrains.com/products.html#IDE_and_editors

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/Debugging+CoffeeScript+Code

Comment: This appears to be for debugging coffee script code client side with a ruby server.  I'm looking for a node js sever side coffee script debugging experience.  Something similar to https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support only visual.

Answer (score 1):

[Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/) has an opened issue [#12 CoffeeScript debugging support](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/12)

Answer (score 0):

You can theoretically do this on any IDE that supports remote debugging.  However, with Coffee-script redux in beta 2 and all the activity surrounding source-map support you would be better off just waiting 5 minutes.