# how to debug coffeescript in node.js with webstorm 6 source maps

Tags: coffeescript, webstorm

I've set up the coffeescript file watcher like in this video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sl1Uk3zT5Fg

Which seems to work fine for an html project debugging with google chrome.  However, when I start debugging and set a breakpoint in the coffeescript file in a node.js project, it doesn't hit the breakpoint.  Setting a breakpoint in the generated js file does however get hit.

What do I need to do for the debugger to use the generated source maps and step through the coffeescript with node.js in webstorm 6?

Comment: Good question!  I am looking for this as well.

Comment: Follow [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7091).

Comment: Hmm looks like the current workaround of moving the generated SourceMapping comment to the bottom of the file is cumbersome and unweildly

Comment: I have a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533885/which-ide-supports-coffeescript-debugging-source-mapping-breakpoints-call-st

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The just released CoffeeScript 1.6.2 now has the annotation for the source map at the bottom as WebStorm expects so it now works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

According to the issue that CrazyCoder mentioned, it looks like it is an issue with WebStorm expecting the `//@ sourceMappingURL=print.map` statement at the bottom of a generated JavaScript file rather than at the top which is where the coffeescript compiler currently puts it.

Manaually copying that line to the bottom of the generated script file on every save seems not a viable workaround so I think we'll have to watch that [Webstorm issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7091)  until it is resolved.