# phpstorm/webide - coffeescript debugger under node.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, phpstorm, web-ide

jetbrains Recently published [blog article about how to debug coffeescript with sourcemaps](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/coffeescript-debugging-with-sourcemaps-in-webstorm-6-phpstorm-6/).

Unfortunatelly this approach can be used only to debug standard javascript runned in some html page (how you can see at the end of article), not node.

I realy need this feature in my node projects, does anybody now how to use it in node.js?

Comment: See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7091.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to debug coffeescript in node.js with webstorm 6 source maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262480/how-to-debug-coffeescript-in-node-js-with-webstorm-6-source-maps)

Comment: Yes it is duplicate, thank you CrazyCoder!